# Unable to access documenst containg predicted label

Tags: text-classification

I am using RTextTools to execute a model I previously trained.  I am unable to extract the document and its predicted label.  I have tried looking at analytics@document_summary and inspecting te container, but need some help getting the approximately 25K documenst and the predicted labels into a data frame for subsequent processing.  Here is the relevant snippett of code:

preddata = read form csv
predsize = nrow(preddata)

preddata$topic <- rep(NA,predsize)

predmatrix <- create_matrix(preddata, originalMatrix=dtMatrix)

predcontainer <- create_container(predmatrix, preddata$topic, testSize=1:predsize, virgin=TRUE)

predresults <- classify_models(predcontainer, models)